# Unique MySQL error message

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a pretty obvious error message from my script, but I know my details are right and that I have grant requests from this web service (000webhost.net). Apparently others on the web are not getting this error and after 3 days of this message, I am getting pretty frustrated! Does anyone know how to fix it through my provider:

> Access denied for user 'a3040562_kputts'@'10.1.1.18' to database 'ireport'

Also, here is the piece of sample code incase others think I am typing in the wrong information:

```
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("mysql4.000webhost.com", "a3040562_kputts", "(censored)") or     die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ireport") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Well, either host, username or password are obviously wrong.

Comment: No one suggests you type something wrong. But that error means the credentials are _not_ accepted. That's it. So maybe that account you use does not exist or does not have sufficient rights or the database does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are successfully connecting to the database server, but your user does not have the necessary MySQL permissions to use that particular database.  You will need to execute a `GRANT` query as a privileged user (or one with `GRANT OPTION` permissions on that database).

To allow this user to use the database (but not necessarily any tables):

```
GRANT USAGE ON ireport.* TO 'a3040562_kputts'@'10.1.1.18';
```

To allow this user full permission on all objects in that database:

```
GRANT ALL ON ireport.* TO 'a3040562_kputts'@'10.1.1.18';
```

Comment: Hmmm...in the "SQL" query section, it is saying access denied there too...did I put it in the wrong place?

Comment: You cannot grant yourself permissions you don't have.  You need to run these queries as a database superuser, or a user with `GRANT OPTION` on this database.  If you don't have access to such a user, contact your hosting provider for assistance.

Comment: Gotcha. I am resending a complaint to them. Thanks. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is the a3040562_kputts your account (as in, no one shares it)? If others use it too, do they access the database from a different location? This error usually crops up when a User account doesn't have the correct permissions to access a database.

You will need someone with higher access to check the permissions table to ensure that account can access the table. If the account can but you are still being denied, get them to double check the 'hosts' field as well (that field controls where a request may come from, sometimes it defaults to 'localhost' so only the server can access itself, I believe if you have permissions on host '*' you can use it from anywhere).

Comment: It is my account...nobody shares it. Though, my host provider is the one maintaining the database. I wonder if there a restriction with 000webhost.net on mysql that I cannot access...I will resend a complaint to the provider again...